# bootstrap carousel button does not work in my react.js app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, cdn

i am try to use bootstrap carousel in react component but i have a problem in next and Previous button.
although the automatically silde to the next item work and the image disply correctly.
also the indicators buttons does not work

here is my component code:

image is array of objects contain Path and Caption

```
import "./ImageSlider.css";

function ImageSlider({ images }) {
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < images.length; i++)
    rows.push(
      <button
        key={i}
        type="button"
        data-bs-target="#ImageSlider"
        data-bs-slide-to={i}
        aria-label={`Slide ${i + 1}`}
      ></button>
    );
  return (
    <div id="ImageSlider" className="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        <button
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#ImageSlider"
          data-bs-slide-to="0"
          className="active"
          aria-current="true"
          aria-label="Slide 1"
        ></button>
        {rows}
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        {images.map((e, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={`carousel-item ${index === 0 ? "active" : ""}`}
              key={index}
            >
              <img
                src={e.Path}
                className="d-block w-100 ProjectImage justify-content-center align-items-center"
                alt={e.Caption}
              />
              <div className="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>{e.Caption}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <button
        className="carousel-control-prev"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target="#ImageSlider"
        data-bs-slide="prev"
      >
        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button
        className="carousel-control-next"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target="#ImageSlider"
        data-bs-slide="next"
      >
        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageSlider;
```

i had use cdn in the index.html

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved ^^

the problem is in the id of the carousels.

Because I called the component multiple times, I had multiple carousels with the same id in the DOM.

so I pass a unique id as a props to the component as shown in the code below

```
import "./ImageSlider.css";

function ImageSlider({ images ,id}) {
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < images.length; i++)
    rows.push(
      <button
        id={i}
        type="button"
        data-bs-target={`#ImageSlider${id}`}
        data-bs-slide-to={i}
        aria-label={`Slide ${i + 1}`}
      ></button>
    );
  return (
    <div id={`ImageSlider${id}`} className="carousel slide ImageSlider" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        <button
          type="button"
          data-bs-target={`#ImageSlider${id}`}
          data-bs-slide-to="0"
          className="active"
          aria-current="true"
          aria-label="Slide 1"
        ></button>
        {rows}
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        {images.map((e, id) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={`carousel-item ${id === 0 ? "active" : ""}`}
              id={id}
            >
              <img
                src={e.Path}
                className="d-block w-100 ProjectImage justify-content-center align-items-center"
                alt={e.Caption}
              />
              <div className="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>{e.Caption}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <button
        className="carousel-control-prev"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target={`#ImageSlider${id}`}
        data-bs-slide="prev"
      >
        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button
        className="carousel-control-next"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target={`#ImageSlider${id}`}
        data-bs-slide="next"
      >
        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageSlider;
```